# error in array of Function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am trying to learn this CLI program but facing issue with an array of function pointer. I am trying to work with sample codes and playing with the same to get a better idea on concepts.

Its a syntax error and i am ubable to trace what is wrong here.

> (*func_ptr[input.opInput])();

I am getting the error as

> " error: called object is not a function or function pointer".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

enum operation {ADD,
        SEARCH,
        LIST,
        DELETE,
        ERROR};

struct data{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char arch[20];
    float rf_freq;
};    //This struct will be dynamically created

struct command {
    enum operation opInput;
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char arch[20];
    float rf_freq;
};

//===========Function proto typing===============
void parseInput(char *inputStr,struct command *cmd);
void createNode(struct data *node);
void deleteNode(struct data *node);
//List of command input supported
void add();
void search();
void list();
void delete();
//===============================================


void (*func_ptr[4])={add,search,list,delete};

int main(void){

struct command input;
char cliInput[80];

printf("Welcome to CLI interface \n Please insert valid command\n");
printf("Valid input format is---->");
printf("wsn> command name arch rf_frequency\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");

while(1){
    printf("wsn>");
    fgets(cliInput,80,stdin);
    parseInput(cliInput,& input);
    (*func_ptr[input.opInput])();    //ERROR
    }//end of while 1
}//end of main

void parseInput(char *inputStr,struct command *cmd){
char *tknstrs[6];
int ii=0;

tknstrs[ii]=strtok(inputStr," \n");
while(tknstrs[ii]){
    tknstrs[++ii]=strtok(NULL," \n");
}

if(strcmp(tknstrs[0],"add")==0)
    cmd->opInput=ADD;
else if(strcmp(tknstrs[0],"search")==0)
    cmd->opInput=SEARCH;
else if(strcmp(tknstrs[0],"list")==0)
    cmd->opInput = LIST;
else if(strcmp(tknstrs[0],"delete")==0)
    cmd->opInput = DELETE;
else
    cmd->opInput = ERROR;

cmd->id=atoi(tknstrs[1]);
strcpy(cmd->name,tknstrs[2]);
strcpy(cmd->arch,tknstrs[3]);
cmd->rf_freq = atof(tknstrs[4]);
}//end of parseInput function

void add(){
}
void search(){
}
void list(){
}
void delete(){
}
```

Thank you for your effort, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a wrong declaration:

```
void (*func_ptr[4])={add,search,list,delete};
```

should be

```
void (*func_ptr[4])()={add,search,list,delete};
-------------------^^ You need also the type of the parameters or empty
```

Notice that you don't need to specify the number of elements of the array (you can avoid typing 4)

Also, prefer using `void` if the function doesn't take arguments:

```
void (*func_ptr[])(void)={add,search,list,delete};
```

and change the prototypes:

```
void add(void);
```

Comment: Thanks @Keine Lust, it solved the issue. Simple syantx error on my end. Its giving segment fault error at ''strcpy(cmd->name,tknstrs[2]);
strcpy(cmd->arch,tknstrs[3]);" any ideas on that?

Comment: Yes, you need space for store those strings, `char *tknstrs[6];` is an array of pointers, you want a 2D array like `char tknstrs[6][50];`, another option is to reserve space for those pointers using `tknstrs[0] = malloc(50);` up to you if you want to use the heap or the stack.

Comment: Hey...the issue was with the size of tknstrs[]. Increasing the size of pointers to 10 solved the issue. Thank you Keine.

Comment: Note that if you give the size of an array as `[]` and initialize it, the compiler will make it the size of the initializer-list. Also, if you’re not going to be altering the contents of an array or variable, it’s wise to declare it `const`.